# Hex To Int In Python No Int Constructor

Tags: python, string, hex, string-parsing

I'm trying to turn a string representing a Hexidecimal number into an int in python without using the int constructor.

For example if I was given

```
    hexstring = "802"
```

How would I get that to be

```
    output = 2050
```

Without doing

```
    int("802",16)
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Why would you *need* to avoid `int`?

Comment: @chepner: common homework problem, with a constraint to prevent the trivial answer.

Comment: You could do `int()`'s work yourself, i.e. parse "802" into its component parts of `(2 * 1) + (0 * 16) + (8 * 256)`.

Comment: `for i in range(0,<big number>): if hex(i)[2:] == hexstring: return i` -- just kidding, don't do this.

Comment: One way would be to use the values of this list: `weird_numbers = [ord(x) for x in hexdigits]`, perhaps in relation to the values of `ord('0')` and `ord('a')` (and/or `ord('A')`)...

Answer (score 2):

```
hexstring = "802"
L=len(hexstring)

def val(h_char):
    # Note you need to extend this to make sure the lowercase hex digits are processed properly
    return ord(h_char)- (55 if ord(h_char)>64 else 48)

def sumup(sum,idx):
    global hexstring # global variables are not recommended
    L=len(hexstring)
    return sum + 16**idx*val(hexstring[L-idx-1])

output = reduce(lambda a,b:sumup(a,b),range(L),0))
```

**Below is just an explanation of the above and doesn't add any value**
Processes on a list of `[0,1,2]` produced by `range(L)`.

For each `idx` from above list a function call is made as `sumup(sum, idx)=sum+16^idx*h_digit_at_idx`.(`^ is ** is exp` in above)

`h_digit_at_idx = ord(h_char)- (55 if ord(h_char)>64 else 48)`

`ord(h_char)` produces `48,49...57,65,66,67,68,69,70` for hex characters `0,1...10,A,B,C,D,E,F`

`ord(h_char)-(55 if ord(h_char)>64 else 48` produces `0,1...10,11,12,13,14,15` for respective chars.

Finally the last argument of the [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function is `0`(which is the initial sum to start with)

Comment: Nice, yeah my solution used a "reducer" like 16*a + b (after turning the string into a list of integers in [0,16] with a similar `ord` trick.

Comment: Also this will produce unreliable results if lower case letter are input as hex digits. I hope OP can edit the statement to add that extra condition for lowercase hex digits.